# How can I get JSON response back (PHP)

Tags: php, angularjs

I am facing  the problem with server response. My goal is to send some data to the server and  obtain some response taking into consideration of  sent data.

Here is my request:

```
$scope.getCities = function () {
        $http.post(getCity, angular.toJson({country: "Belarus"})).then(function (data) {
            $scope.cities = data.data;
            console.log( 'Success' );
        }, function (err) {
            console.log('err');
        });
    };
```

And here is my php code:

```
<?php

$postdata = file_get_contents('php://input');
$request = json_decode($postdata, true);

$country = $request['country'];

//here goes some code

$arr = array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2); // just for example

header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo json_encode($arr);

?>
```

And I see the same error in my console:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Here is my getCity variable:
In the module I have as fallows:

```
calcM.constant("getCity", "http://www.vashagent.by/city_request");
```

In .htaccess I have as fallows:

```
RewriteRule ^city_request$ /wp-includes/getCitiesByCountry.php [L]
```

Comment: What is the value of your `getCity` JS variable?

Comment: Is your request even reaching the php file?

Comment: Also, you don't need to use `angular.toJson`. Angular will serialise the `data` object to JSON by default

Comment: @Phil calcM.constant("getCity", "http://www.vashagent.by/city_request");

Comment: @SaurabhSharma Yes, I have the same scenario with PHP-Mailer

Comment: I'll ask again; what is the **actual** value of your `getCity` JS variable? Show it in your question as comment formatting isn't as robust

Comment: You should also be able to see the request in your browser's *Network* console. What URL is it trying to request?

Comment: That URL appears to be returning a 404. The problem isn't in your Angular or PHP code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143347/discussion-between-p-shustenko-and-phil).